# Deleted table appears while generating entities (using doctrine) in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, mapping

I had a table "user" and later i renamed this to "Users", but while generating entities with  doctrine: generate entities command, the deleted table always appears. Surprisingly, the same table is not appearing among in doctrine orm.xml files list.

I had removed all orm.xml files, entities files, cleared cache and tried again, but still the same error appears.

It will be really helpful if someone can guide me since im a beginner in doctrine.

Thanks and regards,
Tismon Varghese

Comment: How did you define the table and how did you rename it? Can you post some code?

Comment: table created in mysql with "create table" command and renamed using phpmyadmin rename option.

Comment: If you generate your entity from the command line, it will generate that table based on the entity name. In the XML files you deleted (they should come back when you generate), you have the option to change the table name. Don't change it manually in SQL.

Comment: Also I suggest using annotations (or yml) for this instead of xml. You can find more info in the docs, it also shows how to change the table name: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information